# mount a networkdrive in centos 7 : mount error(13): Permission denie

Tags: linux, cifs

Struggling from past 2 days to find out how to mount a network drive(a windows share) in centos7. I went through many forums tried different ways but could not.

I am using following command following command:

```
sudo mount -v -t cifs /windowsip/Test  /testmount -o username=domain/administrator,workgroup=hostname,password="d0m@in",vers=2.1,sec=ntlm
```

tried with many options like: iocharset=utf8,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777

but it is not at all helping.

I have following samba and cifs client installed in my system:

```
cifs-utils-6.2-9.el7.x86_64
samba-client-4.4.4-14.el7_3.x86_64
```

NOTE: I tried passing a credentials file also in the command which also didnt work.

```
sudo mount -v -t cifs //windowsip/Test  /testmount -o credentials=/home/backup/credentials.txt
```

same command is working from one other system (I don't think there is any problem with the command)
Please let me know if there's any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

sudo mount -t cifs -o user=DOMAIN/user_name,sec=ntlmssp //192.168.xxx.xxx/dir/source_dir/ /dest_dir/local_machine

Above command worked in centOS7 - in the destination machine run the above command.
//192.168.xxx.xxx/dir/source_dir/ - source directory
/dest_dir/local_machine - the machine where you want to mount the source directory

Comment: You can use ctrl-k with code selected or `` around it to format it properly.

Comment: Got the solution long ago (it was my server's domain name causing issues). Well, Thanks guys for answering. :-)